# Grounding Wires in Circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity

I recently came across this setup, and I was confused why all these schematics had grounding wires in them. Why would such circuits have grounding wires in them, and would anything happen if they were removed?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing the reason for showing ground connections and what is being asked in connection with the circuits shown.

But, insofar as determining the currents and voltages across each of the resistors shown, nothing would happen if the ground connections wasn't there. You would simply do loop analysis using Kirchhoff's voltage law.

On the other hand, if they want to know what the potential at various nodes in the circuit is, you would need to know what point is considered to be at zero potential, i.e. what point is grounded. That's because a ground connection is typically defined as zero potential in a circuit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The ground symbol indicates that the wire to which it is attached is to be considered $0$ volts.

If no actual connection to ground is made, it would have no effect on the circuit.